# Detect when finger is lifted from screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying with:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


}
```

but it work only if finger was not in moviment. Thanks

Comment: `touchesEnded` is called when you lift the finger. What else you need ??

Comment: touchEnded is called only if the finger was stopped in a point (a single tap). I need to detect when I finish a swipe

Comment: Please edit your question (subject and content) so that it actually asks the question you'd like answered then - "How do I detect when a swipe is finished?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
`touchesEnded:withEvent:`
`Tells the receiver when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.`

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

`Parameters`
**touches**
A set of UITouch instances that represent the touches for the ending phase of the event represented by event.
**event**
An object representing the event to which the touches belong.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand... it work only if my finger make a tap! Not if I move it into the screen before removing it

Comment: For moving you need `touchesMoved:withEvent:`. Please go through docs

Comment: I think I'm not clear explaning... I need to detect when the finger is removed from the screen after a move of the finger

Comment: for that `touchesEnded:withEvent:` is called. Why are you not understanding. It has worked and docs says the same. And I don't know where you are facing the problem with this method

Comment: in my app.. touchesEnded:withEvent work ONLY if I make a simple tap. But If I try to move my finger.. end after moving I remove it from screen, nothin happen

Comment: @user1639377 I have tested it right now and it's working. You should try it with a very simple test project then you will know

Comment: Oh yes I can see that in the Touch Example by Apple everything work as you say... but not im my app.. Why?? In my app it work only with simple taps

Comment: You have to find that because we don't have your project

Comment: I have a mapView in background... can be this the problem?

Comment: Oh Yes I noticed that the problem is the mapView... above the mapView the touchesEnded do not work properly!

Comment: @user1639377 you can also check in that case if `touchesCancelled:`.This is another delegate method like `touchesEnded`

Comment: no everything work only if I made touch abobe the main view and not above other objects like a mapView... I need to find a solution to get the touch on a mapView too

Answer (score 1):

The method should work even if your finger is moving, maybe problem has probably something to do with a UIGestureRecognizer perhaps a UISwipeGestureRecognizer if you are using one.

If you are indeed using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer, you could try to set:

```
[yourGesture setDelaysTouchesBegan:NO]; //default = NO
[yourGesture setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO]; //default = YES
```

If those are set to yes, it will cause the UIGestureRecognizer to analyse the touch before sending it to the other view's

```
[yourGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]; //default = YES
```

This one causes touchesCancelled:withEvent: to be sent to the view for all touches recognized as part of this gesture immediately before the action method is called

Also if your UIGestureRecognizer require's other gesture's to fail, this may cause the problem:

```
- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

Try it out!